# Quicktime Version 7.7.9 On Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: quicktime

I've just installed Quicktime Version 7.7.9 (1680.95.84) on my PC, which uses Windows 10 64-bit. However, when I try to run it, I am informed 'Some of your Quicktime software is out of date'. Can someone tell me if there is a newer version of this software, please?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't; QuickTime does not support Windows 10; Furthermore Apple does not support QuickTime on any version of Windows at this time

Answer (score 1):

There aren't and won't be any newer versions of QuickTime because QuickTime for Windows is no longer supported. Apple [urges](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/04/18/apple-confirms-quicktime-for-windows-end-of-life) all Windows users to uninstall QuickTime as it has severe security problems and those problems will never be patched.

Apple's official guide to uninstall QuickTime : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205771